# Copy the extra information lines from *Org Agenda*

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

It's somehow strange.

In the `*Org Agenda*` you can get extra information with `v c` (time gaps) or `v E` (some entry text).

What I want is just to copy the extra information (text lines) with the rest of the text, so just to copy all the text from the `*Org Agenda*` buffer -- nothing else.

I have tried `org-copy-visible` or even `C-x C-w`; org ignores the extra information and doesn't copy them.
`C-x h` also ignores the extra information lines.

How can I copy the whole buffer text?

Comment: The reason it's not saved is that the extra text  is an [overlay](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlays.html#Overlays). Not sure if there is any way for that to be saved, but you might want to try `C-x C-w` in the agenda and choose an output file with a `.org` extension: it's not the same, but it might serve.

Comment: @NickD Thanks for your answer but I just need the text of the buffer (not the complete items).

Comment: The point of my comment was that you cannot get "just ... the text of the buffer" since some of it consists of overlays (at least AFAIK: somebody else may know better). So you may have to settle for something less or at least something different than what you hope for.

Comment: Though it's an extra step, you might have a look at [Overlays to text](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OverlaysToText).  In your example, it successfully copies all visible text, although the time gaps aren't located in their correct position.  Then you can select anything you want from the resulting buffer.

Comment: I promoted my comment to an answer after seeing it upvoted.  @rl1 will this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Although it's an extra step, you might have a look at [Overlays to text](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OverlaysToText).

In your example, using that function by typing `M-x overlays-to-text` successfully copies all visible text, including the extra lines from `v E` and the time gap information from `v c`.

The function places all that text in a new buffer.  You can select anything you want from the resulting buffer.

Comment: As you have said "although the time gaps aren't located in their correct position. " The position is not correct and some text is copied twice. I upvote your answer and wait - maybe  there is something more suitable.